# Why doesn't composer install Laravel globally in /usr/bin?

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, path, installation, composer-php

The Laravel [installation guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation#installing-laravel) says:

> First, download the Laravel installer using Composer:
>
> ```
> composer global require "laravel/installer"
> ```
>
> Make sure to place the `$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin` directory (or the
>   equivalent directory for your OS) in your `$PATH` so the `laravel`
>   executable can be located by your system.

Why can't laravel just be installed to `/usr/bin` like a normal executable?

Is making a symlink instead of adding the path a good idea?

```
ln -s $HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin /usr/bin/laravel
```

Why doesn't composer do this by default?

Comment: This is a good question to ask the developers of Laravel directly. Why do they need an application to be run locally at all? The placement of it is simply following the way you install it with Composer.

Comment: @Sven the global installation allows you to make a new laravel site with the simple command `laravel new %targetfolder%`.

Comment: symlink is fine, but why not adding this path to your $PATH ? you will have other executables from composer that you'll have to do the same for. packages like: valet, homestead, kirby ad so many others..

Comment: One benefit: You can install programs to your home directory as a regular user. Writing to `/usr/bin/` requires elevated privileges.

Answer (score 1):

on MacOS 10.12 I have solve the issue.
after execute the command on terminal

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

composer will install laravel/installer on your computer.

Find the location where is installed Laravel installer. Then add a line on `~/.bash_profile`

`export PATH=<laravel installer location>:$PATH`

On my cace `<laravel installer location>` was `/Users/shahriar/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/bin/`

So I have added the line on `.bash_profile`

```
export PATH=/Users/shahriar/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/bin:$PATH
```

then type a command on terminal `source ~/.bash_profile` it will update your .bash_profile

and its worked. and now my Laravel installer installed globally.